# javascript function doesn't work twice

Tags: javascript, dom

i'm teaching myself to write native javascript, and i created this function that checks the div to see if it has children, and if not, then it creates a div with a class of 'card'.

the function works when i pass in an argument, but when i do it back to back, it ignores the first function instance and only outputs the second. any ideas?

thanks!

here's my code:

JavaScript:

```
var dealerCards = document.querySelector('.dealer-cards');
var playerCards = document.querySelector('.player-cards');
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');

function cardCheck(a){  
    if (a.firstChild == null) {

        console.log(a.firstChild, a);

        newDiv.className = 'card';

        return a.appendChild(newDiv);

    }
}

cardCheck(dealerCards);
cardCheck(playerCards);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="dealer-box box">
    <h2>Dealer</h2>
    <div class="dealer-cards card-wrapper"></div>
</div>
<div class="player-box box">
    <h2>Player</h2>
    <div class="player-cards card-wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/rehozu/1/edit?html,js

Comment: is there anyway that the condition in the `if` statement is false and it isn't executing the code?  I would use an else statement to check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create the new element inside the function. If you are appending an element that already exists in the document, the element is **moved** to its new parent, not cloned.

From the [**MDN documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild):

> If `child` is a reference to an existing node in the document, `appendChild` moves it from its current position to the new position (i.e. there is no requirement to remove the node from its parent node before appending it to some other node).
>
> This also means that a node can't be in two points of the document simultaneously. So if the node already has a parent, it is first removed, then appended at the new position.
>
> You can use [Node.cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode) to make a copy of the node before appending it under the new parent. (Note that the copies made with cloneNode will not be automatically kept in sync.)

Comment: what would that look like. I know what you're saying. I I'm just having a hard time visualizing it.

Comment: Move the line `var newDiv = document.createElement('div');` inside the function, so that a new element is created every time the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clone the newDiv element in order to manipulate it. Basically you are keeping reference to it and working with already pasted newDiv at the second function call.

[Check it out](http://jsbin.com/dixakihu/2/)